# can MCMCglmm incorporate spatial autocorrelation

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

Recently some colleagues and I used the Bayesian mixed modeling library MCMCglmm to incorporate non-independence between species in a comparative study. 
Now I’m wondering whether the same program could be used to incorporate non-independence between sites in a study where there’s some spatial autocorrelation, as indicated by Moran’s I test.
MCMCglmm has some properties that I’d like to have. It can do generalized linear mixed models (unlike nlme’s gls function, recommended by Dormann et al. Ecography 2007 as one way incorporate spatial autocorrelation).  Our analysis for this project includes analysis of a binomially distributed variable. And unlike lme4, it can use a covariance matrix as a random factor, so presumably it could use some sort of matrix of the distances between sites.
But in our previous project my colleagues were the ones who did the nitty-gritty work of preparing the random factor of phylogenetic history, so I’m not sure exactly how that matrix was set up.
Anyway, wondering whether the idea makes sense.
Thanks for your input!